# how to bring the PDE $u_{tt}-u_{xx} = x^2 -t^2$ to the canonical form

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, multivariable-calculus, partial-differential-equations

How to bring to the canonical form and solve the below PDE?

$$u_{tt}-u_{xx} = x^2 -t^2$$

I recognize that it is a hyperbolic PDE, as the $b^2-4ac=(-4(1)(-1))=4 > 0$.

I don't know how to proceed further to get the canonical form.

I know how to deal with something like $u_{tt}-u_{xx} = 0$.
With $\ RHS =0 \ $ I would use the equation for characteristic 
$R (\frac{\partial^2 dy}{\partial dx})-2S (\frac{\partial^2 dy}{\partial dx})+T=0$ , define the $\xi$ and $\eta$ in terms of $x$ and $y$, calculate the first and second partial derivatives and substitute them into the initial equation.

Here the function on the right hand side $x^2 -t^2$ complicates matter.

How the RHS=X^2-t^2 changes the standard wave equation $u_{tt}−u_{xx}=0$ in terms of interpretation?

Answer (score 3):

Proceed as for $u_{tt}-u_{xx}=0$. You will find $\xi=x+t$, $\eta=x-t$. Then
$$
x^2-t^2=(x+t)(x-t)=\xi\,\eta.
$$

Comment: I have got $2u_{\xi \eta}=\xi \eta$  and then $u(\xi, \eta)=\frac{1}{2}(\frac{1}{4} \xi^2 \eta^2 +F(\xi)+G(\eta))$ is this correct?

Comment: and the general solution $u(x,y)=\frac{1}{8}(x^4+2x^2 t^2+t^4)+\frac{1}{2}(F(x+t)+G(x-t))$

Comment: in terms of interpretation how the RHS=X^2-t^2 changes the standard wave equation $u_{tt}-u_{xx} = 0$?

Comment: @ Michal : Did you put your result $u(x,y)=\frac{1}{8}(x^4+2x^2t^2+t^4)+\frac{1}{2}\left(F(x+t)+G(x-t)\right)$  into $u_{tt}-u_{xx}=x^2-t^2$ in order to check it ? You might be surprised.

Comment: There is an error in your calculation. It should be $-4\,u_{\xi\eta}=\xi\,\eta$. The solution is then $-\dfrac{1}{16}\xi^2\,\eta^2$, and in terms of the original variables $-\dfrac{1}{16}(x^4-2\,x^2\,t^2+t^4)$. The term $x^2-t^2$ represents an external force. It is not realistic, but allows for the explicit solution of the equation.

Comment: @JJacquelin, I checked and it was working because I did two mistakes. I dropped the minus in the canonical equation and took incorrect order for the initial equation $u_{xx}-u_{tt}$ instead of $u_{tt}-u_{xx}$ so the errors were offsetting each other.

Comment: @Julián Aguirre I worked out the correct answer. I think it should be $-2u_{\xi \eta}=\xi \eta$  and the general solution would be $u(x,y)=-\frac{1}{8}(x^4+2x^2t^2+t^4)+F(x+t)+G(x-t)$ which gives $u_{tt}-u_{xx}=- \frac{1}{8} (12t^2+4x^2-12x^2-4t^2)=-\frac{1}{8} (8t^2-8x^2)=x^2-t^2$

Comment: @Julián Aguirre the $u_{tt}=u_{\xi \xi}+u_{\eta \eta}$  the $u_{\xi \eta}$ goes away here as the $\eta=x-t$ and the $\frac{\partial \eta}{\partial t}=-1$, therefore the canonical form is $-2u_{\xi \eta}$ not $-4u_{\xi \eta}$.   do you agree?

Comment: $u_x=u_\xi+u_\eta$, $u_{xx}=u_{\xi\xi}+2\,u_{\xi\eta}+u_{\eta\eta}$, $u_t=u_\xi-u_\eta$, $u_{tt}=u_{\xi\xi}-2\,u_{\xi\eta}+u_{\eta\eta}$.

Comment: @Julián Aguirre I see my mistakes, you are right. I had an incorrect sign in two places. The canonical solution should be $-4u_{\xi \eta}=\xi \eta$ and the general solution should be $u(x,y)=-\frac{1}{16}(x^4-2x^2t^2+t^4)$ which fulfills the initial equation. So theoretically there are 3 different equation and each could be a solution to the initial equation, does it mean the problem is incorrectly posed?

Comment: The problem has no initial condition, so that the concept of well poshness does not apply. The general solution depends on two arbitrary functions, and is of the form $u+F(x+t)+G(x-t)$, where $U$ is the one of your last comment.

Answer (score 3):

$$u_{tt}-u_{xx}=x^2-t^2$$
An obvious particular solution is $u=\frac{1}{12}(-x^4-t^4)$

The change of function : $u(x,t)=v(x,t)+\frac{1}{12}(-x^4-t^4)$ leads to :
$$v_{tt}-v_{xx}=0$$
$$v(x,t)=F(x+t)+G(x-t)$$
$F$ and $G$ are any derivable functions.
$$u(x,t)=F(x+t)+G(x-t)-\frac{1}{12}(x^4+t^4)$$

Comment: How the RHS=X^2-t^2 changes the standard wave equation $u_{tt}−u_{xx}=0 $ in terms of interpretation?

Comment: $u(x,y)=-\frac{1}{8}(x^4+2x^2t^2+t^4)+F(x+t)+G(x-t)$ should work either, how should be those two solutions interpreted?

Comment: The two solutions are the same, but with a different typography of the arbitrary functions. $$-\frac{1}{8}(x^4+2x^2t^2+t^4)=-\frac{1}{12}(x^4+t^4) -\frac{1}{48} (x+t)^4 -\frac{1}{48}(x-t)^4$$ Then $F(x+t) -\frac{1}{48}(x+t)^4=f(x+t)\:\:$ and $\:\:G(x-t)-\frac{1}{48}(x-t)^4=g(x-t)$ $$-\frac{1}{8}(x^4+2x^2t^2+t^4)+F(x+t)+G(x-t)=-\frac{1}{12}(x^4+t^4)+f(x+t)+g(x-t)$$

Answer (score 0):

Summarizing the solution should be

the canonical form $\mathbf{-4u_{\xi \eta}=\xi \eta}$

the general solution $\mathbf{u(x,y)=-\frac{1}{16}(x^4-2x^2t^2+t^4)}$

$\mathbf{x^2-t^2}$ represent an external force